# Plotting multiple box plots as a single graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to plot multiple box plots as a single graph. The data is where I have done a wilcoxon test. It should be like this

[image]

I have four/five questions and I want to plot the respondent score for two sets as a box plot. This should be done for all questions (Two groups for each question).

I am thinking of using ggplot2. My data is like

```
q1o <- c(4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,4,4,3,4)
q1s <- c(5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4)

q2o <- c(3,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,4)
q2s <- c(5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,4,4)

....
....
```

q1 means question 1 and q2 means question 2. I also want to know how to align these stacked box plots based on my need. Like one row or two rows.

Comment: Show us what you've tried; where did you get stuck? Tutorials on how to use `ggplot` are plenty abound. Key words in your case are `?facet_wrap` and `?geom_boxplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

Unfortunately you don't provide a minimal example with sample data, so I will generate some random sample data.

```
# Generate sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    value = rnorm(1000),
    Label = sample(c("Good", "Bad"), 1000, replace = T),
    variable = sample(paste0("F", 5:11), 1000, replace = T));

# ggplot
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = paste0("F", 5:11))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill = Label)) +
        geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge()) +
        facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 3, scale = "free");
```

[image]

You can specify the number of columns and rows in your 2d panel layout through arguments `ncol` and `nrow`, respectively, of `facet_wrap`. Many more details and examples can be found if you follow `?geom_boxplot` and `?facet_wrap`.

---

### Update 1

A boxplot based on your sample data doesn't make too much sense, because your data are not continuous. But ignoring that, you could do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
    q1o = c(4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,4,4,3,4),
    q1s = c(5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4),
    q2o = c(3,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,4),
    q2s = c(5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,4,4));

df %>%
    gather(key, value, 1:4) %>%
    mutate(
        variable = ifelse(grepl("q1", key), "F1", "F2"),
        Label = ifelse(grepl("o$", key), "Bad", "Good")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill = Label)) +
        geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge()) +
        facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 3, scale = "free");
```

[image]

---

### Update 2

One way of visualising discrete data would be in a `mosaicplot`.

```
mosaicplot(table(df2));
```

[image]

The plot shows the count of `value` (as filled rectangles) per `Variable` per `Label`. See `?mosaicplot` for details.

Comment: Can you show one using q1o,q1s and q2o,q2s. F1 is a boxplot with q1o,q1s  and F2 is a boxplot with q2o,q2s. Then it should be helpful for me to scale to more such sets q3o,q3s,....

Comment: @user567879 Please see my updated answer; IMO a boxplot doesn't make much sense, seeing that your data are discrete rather than continuous.

Comment: Then what would be the best method for a graphical representation for comparing q1o and q1s ? I have four questions and data are collected from 30 respondents for these questions (same respondents for q1o and q1s)

Comment: @user567879 That's a very different question from your original post. It seems that this is more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest closing the question by accepting the answer. If you want to *compare* two discrete distributions, you could use either a chi-square test, or a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. In terms of *visualising* discrete/categorical data, perhaps take a look at [this paper](http://www.datavis.ca/books/vcd/vcdstory.pdf) as a starting point.

Comment: An example/starting point could be a `mosaicplot`. Please see my updated solution.